# Facebook API: cannot login on Android

Tags: android, api, authentication, facebook-login

I'm trying to implement Facebook login on Android, using the Facebook API. I've done everything the way [Facebook Login Flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/) says. The code is below.

```
public class FBSignIn extends Fragment {
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Sign In");
        reloadTemplate();

        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean executeCommand(BaseWebView webView, String command, String data) {

        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
            Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

            if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
                loginWithFBToken(session.getAccessToken());
                return;
            }

            Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, callback);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            // Facebook logged in...

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            //Facebook logged out...
        }
    }

}
```

However, after the `Session.openActiveSession()` call, in `onSessionsStateChange()` function, I first get `state == CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED`; after that it's called the second time, with `state == OPENING`. So it never gets into an `OPENED` state.

What's wrong with this code? I'd very much appreciate your help.

P.S. I've commented out everything concerning `uiHelper` and, in my main activity, supplied the overriden method:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Now the first call to `onSessionStateChange` comes with `state == OPENING` and `exception == null`. The 2nd call comes with `state == CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED` and `exception == Invalid access token`. What does that mean?

Comment: Are you sure your app has been authorized on the Facebook end? What's the error code coming from FB?

Comment: Yes, I have Application ID, and it's specified in `AndroidManifest.xml`. As for the error code, please, see P.S. that I've just written.

Comment: Tushar, you were right. My mistake. The reason was the incorrect (or sth wrong with) application id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue. The reason was that our app was registered in Facebook in Sandbox mode, and only certain users could log in with Facebook. When I logged in under one of these accounts, it worked.

Comment: OMG! YOU saved my LIFE! I have developer account on the other login that, I was using..

OMG THANKS!!!!!